# Read page source using PHP with primes "

Tags: php

I am trying to read the source code of a page. I just want to read some text that is within a certain division element with the id "wrapper_left".

My problem is that if a prime " is used in the first argument of the explode function, it does not work. I tried escaping the string, although I figured this wouldn't do anything.

```
$source_code = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com'));

$source_code = explode('<div id="wrapper_left">', $source_code);

echo $source_code[1];
```

Thanks tons in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `explode` ? sounds like using `strpos` and then `substr` would work better.

Comment: if you want to remove html tag yoau can als try `$text = '<b>This is an example</b>';
$strippedText = strip_tags($text);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bother trying to get this done with `explode()`, string manipulation, or a regular expression, you need an HTML parser, like [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile( 'http://mydomain.com');

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc);
$div = $xpath->query( '//div[@id="wrapper_left"]')->item(0);
echo $div->textContent;
```

You can see it working in [this demo](http://3v4l.org/i1b0m), which, when fed this HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper_left">Some text</div>
```

It produces:

```
Some text
```